# Long iPhone voice memos won't import to my Mac

Tags: data-synchronization, iphone

I recorded a lengthy meeting today in two parts.  The first part was 20 minutes, and it was easily imported to my Mac.  The second, about 55 minutes, will not sync.  It is still on the phone, but I want to transfer it to my computer so that I can create an MP3 version.

Can anyone tell me whats wrong?

Comment: hmm... weird for sure

Answer (score 2):

Yesterday I just created a 2h recording using the standard Apple's Voice Memo and "imported" seamlessly to my Mac, no issues at all. It went to my music library in an album "Voice Memos".

I can only say there's nothing special that should cause such an issue and I confirmed it. What I would do in your case is checking the [Console](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Console_%28Mac_OS_X%29) hoping for some informative warning and trying to record another file and see how that goes.

But there's a good chance you've got it and is just not finding it, like [other dudes](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2568644&tstart=1). Worst case scenario, get [iPhone Explorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iphoneexplorer/) and grab them manually. There are [some steps](http://discussions.info.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=12408237#12408237) you might want to follow and see if it helps in you case. The first one is: *Restart you mac*.